# Remember username but not password

Tags: users

I'm on Drupal 7 and have tried the appropriate versions of both the [Persistent Login](http://drupal.org/project/persistent_login) and [Remember Me](http://drupal.org/project/remember_me) modules.  However, I don't want to provide a "remember me" option to remember users' passwords.  Instead, **I want to automatically remember the username and present that pre-filled upon a user's next visit.**

Is there a module for this?  If not, could someone roughly outline the approach I might take to do this (using cookies, etc.)?

Comment: How would you handle multiple users who share the same computer or users who log in on public machines?

Comment: @Clive I'm assuming (wisely or that) that this would not be an issue for the site in question.  For multiple users sharing the same computer, it would be a minor inconvenience to clear the username before logging in.  For users on public machines, I don't think it would seriously impact their privacy to have the username stored.

Comment: Ah ok...I guess you'd implement `hook_user_login()` to set a cookie to the relevant username upon login, then implement `hook_form_alter()` for the login form to set the `#default_value` for the username field. Bear in mind nearly every browser allows the user to save usernames/passwords for sites, so you might end up nuking that functionality for those users that have their auth details saved. Or you might not, I haven't tried it :)

Comment: Were you able to implement this? I'm looking for same. Please share code if so.